# Css file in react gets applied to all files even though it was imported in just one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I am learning react and working on a project right now and one thing is getting extremely annoying.

Example, I have the following files:
`script1.js` `stylesheet1.css` and `script2.js` `stylesheet2.css`

In stylesheet1.css if I do:

```
span { blah blah }
button { blah blah}
```

this will always get applied in script2.js **even though** I only imported `stylesheet1.css` in `script1.js`. Now I know i can just use class names or ID names but this is much easier. How to get around this? What am I doing wrong? Basically, all i want is to apply properties for **ALL** the buttons or **ALL** the divs in one `.js` file but it gets applied to the **entire project**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component approach for css like you can create  stylesheet1.module.css and can import in script1.js like

import style from '../stylesheet1.module.css' and use id or class

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you just use classes debugging will be much easier when you run into a problem. Just use the the same class for all the buttons that will do the job.

I had a project where one of my colleague did the styling as you did and  every css code was clashing with each other. The debugging was a nightmare.